# User error: "You do not have authorization to perform that action." Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some GAS currently being run off of a spreadsheet.  They will eventually move to a published service, however, the current issue needs to be resolved first.

I'm running into an issue where a script that I've written, and other users have used in the past are receiving the Subject error message.

A new script I can run (but others cannot) has been taken down to a single test function

```
function hello()
{ Browser.msg("Hello There") }
```

This still generates the **"You do not have authorization to perform that action."**

My older script has had no script changes and now users receive the same error.

Comment: What sharing privileges to the other users have that are trying to access your spreadsheet and script? I believe that Browser.msgBox requires edit access on the spreadsheet in order to run. I suggest either giving the users edit access or trying a call to Logger.log("Hello there"); instead.

Comment: The sharing for my users is 'everyone who has link can edit' no sign-in required.

Comment: In that case, please raise this in the issue tracker and also include the project key for the script, which can be found in the script editor under File > Project Properties. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't updated the Sharing settings on my script.  Maybe that's what Jan was referring to...

Thanks Jan !